# On the support of a function given by an integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces, variational-analysis, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ a bounded smooth domain. Also consider $u \in C^1_{c}(\Omega)$, that is, a function which support is in $\Omega$. I would like to know if the function $\varphi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
\varphi(s) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \frac{|u(x +  se_j) - u(x)|^p}{s^{1 + \alpha_j p}} dx
$$
also has compact support, where $1 < p < +\infty, 0 < \alpha_j < 1$ and $e_j = (0,...0,1,0...0)$, $j=1,...,N$.

**The context:** Is it true that
$$
\int_0^1 \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \frac{|u(x +  se_j) - u(x)|^p}{s^{1 + \alpha_j p}} dx ds = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \frac{|u(x +  se_j) - u(x)|^p}{s^{1 + \alpha_j p}} dx ds \quad?
$$
These integrals are closelly related to anisotropic Sobolev space of order $(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_N)$.

Comment: No. For each $s$, the integrand should be positive on a set of positive measure.

Comment: Dear @daw, thank you for your reply. I didn't understand your tip. You meant that, if there's a set $A$ with positive measure such that $|u(x + se_j) - u(x)|^p/ s^{1 + s_jp} > 0, \forall x \in A$, then $\varphi$ has compact support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\phi(s)=0$ for some $s\ne 0$.
Then
$$
u(x+se_j) = u(x)
$$
for almost all $x$.

Let me assume $s>0$. Since $u$ has compact support, there is $M>0$ such that $u(x)=0$ if $x_j>M$. Using the above relation, we find $u(x)=0$ for all $x$ with $x_j > M-s$. Inductively it follows $u=0$.
The same argument works for $s<0$.

Comment: Thank you very much @day.